# How can I change the icon of a Windows 10 app?

Tags: windows-10

Changing the icon of a Windows program is easy. Just right-click on the program, and go to `Properties` -> `Change Icon`.

But how can I change the icon of a **Windows 10 app**, for example, *OneNote for Windows 10*?

Comment: It is not possible to change the icon of a `Universal Windows Program` (UWP) application which is exactly what `OneNote for Windows` 10 is.

Comment: You can right click on the item shortcut, select Properties and click on Change Icon.  If you can change the icon (some cannot as noted above), the list of possible icons will appear and you can select from that.